# Injecting Application Settings into Azure Functions v3.0 using IOptions<>

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, serverless, azure-function-app

How to Injecting Application Settings into Azure Functions v3.0 using IOptions<>

Always getting JwtIssuerOptions null values

Say our settings file, local.settings.json contains the following data:

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
 "Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
"SqlConnectionString": "Server"
},
"JwtIssuerOptions": {
"JwtKey": "rpqru",
"JwtIssuer": "mydomain",
"JwtExpireDays": 7,
"JwtExpireMinutes": 240,
"JwtAuidence": "localhost"
  }
}
```

Function Startup

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{

```
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var localConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();           
        builder.Services.AddOptions<JwtIssuerOptions>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.Bind("JwtIssuerOptions", settings);
        });
    }
```

JwtIssuerOptions Class Like bellow

```
public class JwtIssuerOptions

  {
        
    public string JwtKey { get; set; }

    public string JwtIssuer { get; set; }

    public int JwtExpireDays { get; set; }

    public int JwtExpireMinutes { get; set; }

    public string JwtAuidence { get; set; }
}
```

Functions Like Bellow

```
   public class MyFunctions
   
 {

  private readonly IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> _options;

  public MyFunctions(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> applicationSettingsOptions, 
  IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions>  options)
  {
 // the named section of the configuration file "JwtIssuerOptions"
  _options;= options;
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the desired options using the section from the built local configuration

*FunctionsStartup*

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
    IConfiguration localConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
         .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();
       
    builder.Services
        .Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(localConfig.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions"));
}
```

Another approach would be to get the local settings, add it to the container

```cs
FunctionsStartup {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
        IConfiguration localConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
        //load setting
        JwtIssuerOptions jwt = localConfig.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").Get<JwtIssuerOptions>();
        //register with container
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<JwtIssuerOptions>(jwt);
    }
}
```

and explicitly inject it into the function

```cs
public class MyFunctions {

    private readonly JwtIssuerOptions jwtOptions;

    public MyFunctions(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> applicationSettingsOptions, 
        JwtIssuerOptions jwtOptions) {
        this.jwtOptions = jwtOptions;

        //...
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a file name ApplicationSettings.cs with all properties names that you are using in you EnvironmentVariables, ok?

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    public string DatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string valueXYZ { get; set; }
    public string CacheConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

after, the best way is to load this config in memory using startup file (if your project don't exists this, create)

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration = null;

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        SetupMaps
            .ConfigureMaps();

        builder
            .Services
            .AddLogging();

        builder
            .Services
            .AddOptions<ApplicationSettings>() <-- YOUR CLASS
            .Configure<IConfiguration>(
            (settings, configuration) => { configuration.Bind(settings); });
    }
```

=== now using in some class

```
namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public class YOUR_CLASS: YOUR_INTERFACE
    {
    private readonly ApplicationSettings _applicationSettings;

    public YOUR_CLASS(
        IOptions<ApplicationSettings> applicationSettings)
    {
        _applicationSettings = applicationSettings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<RETURN_CLASS> METHOD_NAME(string PARAMETER)
    {
    //HERE YOU CAN USE _applicationSettings.PROP
    }
```